# On iOS tappable area

Tags: ios, user-interface

iOS development guidelines [suggest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Characteristics/Characteristics.html) *44* points to be a minimum tappable area, comfortable for a human finger.

> The comfortable minimum size of tappable UI elements is 44 x 44
>   points.

With that in mind, does the following statement automatically contradict with the above

```
[take setFrame:CGRectMake(420,200, 50, 40)];
```

**In other words, is the following true?**

```
 Width and Heights set for any tappable element in iOS must be >= 44?
```

**If not, how would you change it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of tappable element is only suggested by the MobileHIG document. UIKit of CocoaTouch didn't restrict this. If you use a touchpad or mouse in the simulator, you can make a tappable area (UIButton) smaller than this size.

In real world apps, I think I've seen buttons as small as 38 points. But anything less than that might require design revising. Plus, the review team might reject your app because of not following MobileHIG.

Still it's not a strict technical limitation.

Comment: Right. So, from the stand point of review team, every tappable element should be 44+, is this correct?

Comment: Yep, but like I said, they probably won't refuse your app just because a button is 40 points tall. It's the design that matters.